# How to correctly import an aws-sdk-go service?

Tags: go, aws-sdk-go

I am fairly new to the Go programming language and completely new to the Go SDK from AWS. I am trying to use a service but I have a strange problem where the types defined by the imported service are found, but the functions of the service are undefined.

This question is not about using the particular service, but just how to correctly import it. My code:

```
package auth

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/cognitoidentityprovider"
)

func SignUpTest() {

    input := cognitoidentityprovider.SignUpInput{
        Username: aws.String("example@mail.com"),
        Password: aws.String("test1234"),
    }

    _, err := cognitoidentityprovider.SignUp(&input)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

I get the following error when running `go build`:

```
auth/signup.go:18:12: undefined: cognitoidentityprovider.SignUp
```

The autocomplete in my IDE also states that it can find the `cognitoidentityprovider.SingUpInput` struct, but it is unable to find the `cognitoidentityprovider.SignUp` function.

I use Go 1.10.1 on WSL Ubuntu. I use DEP 0.4.1 for package management. I verified that the AWS SDK is available in the vendor folder and that the cognitoidentityprovider package is available (the `SignUp`) function is also there.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says it all. `cognitoidentityprovider.SignUp` isn't defined, because there is no symbol `SignUp` exported by the `cognitoidentityprovider` package.

I'm not really sure what you want to do instead, since I'm not familiar with that SDK, but you're trying to call a function that doesn't exist.  I suggest re-examining the documentation or example you're following. You've probably made a simple mistake.

You seem to be confused by the [CognitoIdentityProvider.SignUp](https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/cognitoidentityprovider#CognitoIdentityProvider.SignUp) instance method. But as that's an instance method, and not an exported function, it requires an instance of a `CognitoIdentityProvider` first:

```
cip := cognitoidentityprovider.New( ... )
_, err := cip.SignUp(input)
```

Comment: The problem is that it does exist in the package and in the documentation? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/cognitoidentityprovider/#CognitoIdentityProvider.SignUp

and

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/service/cognitoidentityprovider/api.go#L8791

Comment: No, it doesn't exist in the documentation. That link you provided is to a method, not an exported function. That method can only be called on a defined `CognitoIdentityProvider` instance.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing this concept, got some working code now.